# How to correctly use telnet in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, telnet, rhel

I am running following command to test port connectivity

```
curl -v telnet://target ip address:desired port number
```

When server connects successfully I see output as below:

```
# curl -v telnet://127.0.0.1:22
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 22 (#0)
* Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 22 (#0)
```

When server doesn't connects successfully I see output as below:

```
# curl -v telnet://127.0.0.1:22
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 22 (#0)
* Trying 127.0.0.1...
```

Now for a given list of servers, I am trying to automate it using bash script.

```
for element in "${array[@]}"; do
        timeout 2s curl -v telnet://"$element":22 >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "'$element' connected" && break
        else
                 echo "Connection with $element failed."
        fi
        done
```

The array has values:

```
abc001
abc002
abc003
```

I am always getting output from within `else` statement

```
Connection with abc001 failed.
Connection with abc002 failed.
Connection with abc003 failed.
```

I think it is because the return code is always `124`

The error code is `124` for both success and failure

How can I modify my script to work correctly?

Comment: Even when the connection succeeds the return code is 124?

Comment: yeah it is 124 for both success and failure

Comment: That's... strange.  Perhaps you could `grep` the output for some string indicating success.

Comment: I can grep for `Connected ` but can you provide the updated script? thanks in advance

Comment: @mealhour : Why are you throwing away the stderr from the _telnet_ command, if you want to find out why the connection is refused? Also, does connection on the command line with, i.e., abc123, work, within the 2 sec timeout window?

Answer (score 2):

You could `grep` the output for some string indicating success.  E.g.,

```
if timeout 2s curl -v telnet://"$element":22 2>&1 | grep "Connected to"; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

Comment: It is still executing `else` statement  `Connection with abc001 failed.
Connection with abc002 failed.
Connection with abc003 failed.`

Comment: Should i add `echo` in the front before `timeout`?

Comment: Are you sure the command is succeeding?  Try capturing the output to a variable, printing the variable, and then running it against grep.  So, `output=$(timeout 2s curl -v telnet://"$element":22 2>&1); echo $output; if echo $output | grep "Connected to"; then ...`

Comment: when i directly run the `curl` command on shell, then it is succeeding

Comment: It seems to be working but `if echo $output` is producing lot of text. should i add `/dev/null` to suppress it? also can you please update the answer so that is helpful to others as well. thanks!!

Comment: The output should be piping the output into `grep`, so you shouldn't be seeing it.  If you're talking about the first `echo` statement, then you can redirect it to a file.  I.e., `echo $output > dump`.  I'd love to help you more but the missus is calling me to bed.  =/

Comment: I have removed the first `echo` statement but i see huge text on the screen. and then in the end i see `abc001 connected` looks like it is coming from `if echo $output | grep "Connected to"`

Answer (score 1):

`curl` has an optional argument `--connect-timeout <seconds>`. My suggestion would be to revise your `curl` command to something like:

```
for element in "${array[@]}"; do
    curl -v --connect-timeout 2 telnet://"${element}":22
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "'${element}' connected"
    else
        echo "Connection with ${element} failed."
    fi
done
```

A good reference would be the [curl man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl).